# Access document info of document opened in any application on windows os

Tags: c#, windows, interop, winforms-interop

As like by using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application** we can access an active instance of Word, then we can get document opened in it and ultimately access that documents info. So can we do the same thing with other applications like Visual Studio/Android Studio too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Mutex. Try this link this might be helpful
https://www.dotnetperls.com/mutex

Comment: Can you give an example how it can be used to access files opened in other application, cause best of my knowledge it is used for thread synchronization

Comment: Did you try the link ? And in your question you mentioned that you need to  do it with application...Right? If so, you can use ProcessInfo for this.

Comment: I need to access other applications info, not my own that is my problem, and yes I went through that link and other similar articles too but not getting how exactly can I access For example, Adobe PDF reader instance and get info about active pdf file opened in it.